# How to fix: Error creating bean with name : Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to set up a spring rest api using hibernate. When trying to use the userRespository I set up I am getting this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.potholeapi.models.User
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.potholeapi.Application.main(Application.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:542) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Here are the Model, Controller and Application Files

Model

```
package com.potholeapi.models;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private int created_date;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getCreated_date() {
        return created_date;
    }

    public void setCreated_date(int created_date) {
        this.created_date = created_date;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package com.potholeapi.controllers;

import com.potholeapi.repositories.UserRepository;
import com.potholeapi.services.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.potholeapi.models.User;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    /**
     * Get all users list.
     *
     * @return the list
     */
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return  userService.getUsers();
    }
}
```

Repository

```
package com.potholeapi.repositories;

import com.potholeapi.models.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {}
```

Service

```
package com.potholeapi.services;

import com.potholeapi.models.User;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface UserService {
    List<User> getUsers();
}
```

ServiceImpl

```
package com.potholeapi.services.impl;

import com.potholeapi.models.User;
import com.potholeapi.repositories.UserRepository;
import com.potholeapi.services.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public List<User> getUsers(){
        List<User> out = new ArrayList<User>();
        userRepository.findAll().forEach(user -> out.add(user));
        return out;
    }
}
```

Application

```
package com.potholeapi;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EntityScan
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.potholeapi.repositories")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <name>potholeAPI</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/PotholeDB?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username = admin
spring.datasource.password = admin

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

directory structure

```
src
-main
--java
---com.potholeapi
----controllers
----models
----repositories
----services
-----impl
-resources
pom.xml
```

What have I missed in setting this up? From all of the tutorials i have looked at online autowired is supposed to work oujt of the box

Comment: (1) `applicationContext.xml` is obsolete with Spring Boot. (2) Package names should use all lowercase; compare with your import statements. (3) `@ComponentScan` and similar configuration annotations are only activated when present on `@Configuration` classes (`@SpringBootApplication` includes that). (4) You need `@EnableJpaRepositories` on your configuration (`Application`).

Comment: I implemented the changes you suggested and I am still getting the same result

Comment: Please update your error message.

Comment: I updated the error message, I believe it is the same

Comment: Okay, please include your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` file and show your directory structure (ASCII art is the usual way). You also might want to try `@ComponentScan({"controllers", "repositories"}) @EntityScan("models")`; I don't remember off the top of my head whether `@EnableJpaRepositories` will find a type that's not already component-scanned (it should, but I'm not certain).

Comment: I added the pom.xml and updated the structure to remove the need for the componentScan decorator

Comment: Remove `@EnableJpaRepositories`, as that is enabled by Spring Boot already. Remove the hibernate and spring-data-jpa dependencies and instead add the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency. Also the junit dependency is already included in the `spring-boot-starter-test` dependency remove that as well (as it is an ancient version).

Comment: @TylerB.Joudrey, Do as M. Deinum said, And check my answer also.

Comment: I followed the suggestions made and I now have a new error, the question and files have been updated

Comment: @TylerB.Joudrey I have modified my answer. Please let me know whether it works or not.

Comment: @TylerB.Joudrey Have you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your `User` class you declare id with `int` type

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id", unique = true)
private int id;
```

But in the repository interface, you declared `Long`

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {}
```

So, in `User` class change type of id like,

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id", unique = true)
private Long id;
```

And avoid your new error, use `@Service` annotation at `UserService` interface like

```
@Service
public interface UserService {
    List<User> getUsers();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**First, you don't have an appropriate project packaging structure. Then, you don't have a base package. Spring always mentions to have a base package for proper component scans. Without base package, it's a bad practice.**

The best practice should be like :

```
src
-main
--base package(x.x.x.) (for example : com.project)
---controllers
---models
---repositories
-resources
```

1. Xml - Based config :

   `<context:component-scan base-package="com.project" />`
2. Annotation or Java- based config :

   `@ComponentScan("com.project")`

Secondly, if you have these kind of package, on a contrary, you have to mention package names separately.

You have to do it like this :

1. Xml - Based config :

   `<context:component-scan base-package="main.controllers, main.repositories" />`
2. Annotation or Java- based config :

   `@ComponentScan({"main.controllers", "main.repositories"})`

Moreover, you are having a spring-boot project. So what you do is add @ComponentScan in the `Application` class :

```
@ComponentScan({"main.controllers", "main.repositories"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("main.repositories")
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

Comment: bless you for providing xml vs java-config vs annotation based answers.

Comment: @granadaCoder Thanks. Always there for people :)

Comment: @AnishB. For me, I have a package `encourage` inside base. Under `base` but outside encouragement is the `Config` class with `@Configuration` which defines the beans. Is that okay?

Answer (score 2):

It may be beneficial for you to fix your package structure. If your main application is at a package called my.base and your controller is at my.base.controllers then you won't have to use the component scans. My suggestion in the current state is to add the repositories package to the component scan so it will find the bean at runtime.

```
@ComponentScan({"controllers", "reposistories"})
```